# delete a layout and reset another one

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget, qlayout

I have

```
QWidget *myWidget; //on my mainWindow with Qt Creator
```

and a

```
QComboBox *myComboBox;
```

When I change my selection of myComboBox, I would like to delete

```
myWidget->layout();
```

and set to myWidget another layout.

I'm doing : (with this help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034868/6105710)

```
void ConfWindow::on_comboBouton_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if(ui->myWidget->layout()){
        auto myLayout = ui->myWidget->layout();
        QLayoutItem *item;
        while((item = myLayout->takeAt(0)) != 0){
            myLayout->removeItem(item);
            delete item;
        }
        delete myLayout;
    }

    for(int i=0; i< someVector->size(); i++){
        if( someVector->at(i)->getName() == arg1){
            ui->myWidget->setLayout( someVector->at(i)->getLayout()); //which return a QHBoxLayout.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and when I change my comboBox, It is painting my new layout, but my old layout still here..
I tried repaint(), update() etc...

Is it because I create layout in another class and add it with

```
auto myVector = new QVector<myClass>; 
setLayout( myVector->getLayout() )
```

? I don't think so because I'm using pointer .. I don't understand ...

Comment: Deleting a layout and creating a new one is very inefficient, especially if the old one can be selected again. I suggest looking into QStackedWidget and link the indexes.

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind wow this is so cool ! Thanks a lot bro !