# How to arrange the items in the default layout of QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qmainwindow

This is the arrangement that I want:

```
------------  ------
|          |  | 2  |
|          |  |    |
|     1    |  ------
|          |  ------  
|          |  |  3 |
------------  ------
```

The problem is that the `addwidget` function of the default layout doesn't have the parameters for rows and columns. I can't even add any `QVBoxLayout` since the compiler says that a layout is already there so you can't add more layouts.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_QPushButton_calibration = new QPushButton("Calibrate", this);
    connect(m_QPushButton_calibration, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));

    QList<QCameraInfo> l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);

    if (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras.length() > 2)
    {
        m_QCamera_required_camera = new QCamera (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras[1]);
        m_QCamera_required_camera->setViewfinder(m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder);
        m_QCamera_required_camera->start ();
    }

    this->layout()->addWidget(m_QPushButton_calibration);
    this->layout()->addWidget(m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder);

    m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder->show();
}
```

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't be doing *anything* with the layout of a `QMainWindow` directly.  Instead you should create the widget hierarchy you need and pass that to [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: @G.M. please consider writing a small example as an answer.

Comment: @G.M. could you give a reference to the docs where it says that `you really shouldn't be doing anything with the layout of a QMainWindow directly`?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Unfortunately the docs  *don't* say that explicitly.  But if you look at the [description of `QMainWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#details) it's obvious that a lot (most) of the functionality it provides over and above a plain `QWidget` is down to its own private layout -- movable toolbars, docking widgets etc.  So even if you do manage to replace the original layout with one of your own all you've really achieved is to turn the `QMainWindow` into a plain `QWidget` -- the extra functionality is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the intended use of `QMainWindow` is that you create your desired widget hierarchy and then pass that to [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).  With that in mind, rather than...

```
this->layout()->addWidget(m_QPushButton_calibration);
this->layout()->addWidget(m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder);
m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder->show();
```

what you could try is something like...

```
QWidget *central_widget = new QWidget;
QGridLayout *grid_layout = new QGridLayout;
central_widget->setLayout(grid_layout);
grid_layout->addWidget(m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder, 0, 0, 2, 1);
grid_layout->addWidget(m_QPushButton_calibration, 0, 1, 1, 1);
setCentralWidget(central_widget);
```

So the widget hierarchy you want is placed under `central_widget` and that, in turn, is passed to `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`.

(Note: I'm guessing as to the placement of m_QCameraViewfinder_viewfinder and m_QPushButton_calibration in the `QGridLayout` and you may want to make `central_widget` and/or `grid_layout` members of your class depending on how you intend to use them.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change a layout of the window to a `QGridLayout`, which supports rows, columns and row/column spans. This can be done with `setLayout()` function.

Note that you must first delete the default layout that is already in-place in the window, which you can get with the `layout()` function. You can refer to [this documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) for additional info.

Just delete it with `delete this->layout()`, but make sure that you set something with `setLayout()` right after that. Also if you have nested layouts you will have to delete them manually.

Comment: I can see `layout()->deleteLater` function. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Just delete it with `delete widget->layout()`, __but__ make sure that you set something with `setLayout()` right after that. Also if you have nested layouts you will have to delete them manually (see the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528680/how-to-delete-an-already-existing-layout-on-a-widget/12034868)

Comment: Wow, I asked that question in 2011! BTW, under that second answer there is a comment. What do you think of it?

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl, Ha! I didn't even notice that question is also yours. It's a little unclear because the documentation on one of `addLayout` overloads says that the parent layout takes possession of the child layout, but the documentation on the other overload doesn't mention it. You might have to check it yourself to make sure, since the behavior might have changes since 2011.

Comment: Or can you shed some light on the new comment on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549303/how-to-arrange-the-items-in-the-default-layout-of-qmainwindow?noredirect=1#comment72236105_42549303

Comment: But, I want to know if we are simply supposed to delete the default layout and then write our own, then what is the use of having a default layout in QMainWindow?